# Find rows that have a larger time string than the current time SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a column within a table that is used to track when something was deleted. All it holds is a timestamp via the php time() function. I now need to find those rows that contain a timestamp created 90 days ago or more. I'm having trouble with this query.

This is what I thought would work

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (table.deleted + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60)) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I think you want to switch the `>=` to `<`.

Comment: Was this issue solved?

Answer (score 4):

What about using intervals?

```
... WHERE table.deleted < (now() - interval 90 DAY)
```

This will fetch all the records whose `table.deleted` value is older than 90 days.

Comment: i think there's no quicker, easier or better way.

Comment: I have 14 total rows in the db for this table. Using this example, the result is giving me all 14 rows when it should only give me a few of the rows.

Comment: @JoshWoelfel Can you give a SQLFiddle or some sample input to play with? Apparently this should make it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the operator to the wrong side. You want files deleted more than 90 days ago so:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (table.deleted + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60)) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Regardless of which side I have the operator, the result is all 14 rows using this example. I should only be receiving less than 14 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE unix_timestamp()-lastrequest>7776000
```

**The above example requires:**

1. Your timestamps in the row must be in unix_timestamp() format (you can create unix timestamps from at least bash, php and mysql)
2. Replacement of "lastrequest" with your row's name

You actually subtract current timestamp (unix_timestamp() in MySQL) from your row's content and check if the difference is bigger than 7776000 (which means 90 days)

Hope it helps.